# Is the _numberMinted() function of ERC721A a good replacement for a mapping that stores values for addresses?

Tags: gas, erc-721, mapping

The way I've seen it (very stripped down example) (ERC721):

```
uint256 public maxPer = 5;
mapping(address => uint256) public countsByAddress;

function myMint(uint256 qty) external payable {
    require(countsByAddress[_msgSender()] + qty <= maxPer, "Exceeds limit");
    
     countsByAddress[_msgSender()] += qty;
    _safeMint(_msgSender(), qty);
}
```

Can this be replaced by (ERC721A):

```
function myMint(uint256 qty) external payable {
    require(_numberMinted(_msgSender()) + qty <= maxPer, "Exceeds limit");

    _safeMint(_msgSender(), qty);
}
```

Are there downsides to the `_numberMinted()` approach? Does it save gas?

Comment: I don't know what "_numberMinted()" does, but I'm pretty sure it calls a function that checks on the mapping. So probably it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It seems ERC721A `_numberMinted()` function internally reads a mapping, so it's essentially just a convenience function to do the exact same thing as the first example. `_numberMinted()` seems like the better option in that it removes the need to maintain a mapping yourself.